# How to remove white border line of rectangles in Altair heatmap/mark_rect plots?

Tags: python, visualization, altair

I am trying to plot a heatmap with 400 rows and 12 columns, and the formatting of the borders of the rectangles makes the outcome look unexspected, see image below.

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_rect().encode(
  x='time_point:O',
  y=alt.Y('row_id',
          sort=alt.EncodingSortField(field=col,
          op="sum",
          order='ascending'),
          axis=None),
  color='binary_measure:N'
).properties(
  width=200,
  height=200
)
```

[image: Heatmap with unexpected border effects]

I realize it looks here like the borders are darker, but it's actually a white or lighter color line, see this reproducible example:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

alt.Chart(source).mark_rect().encode(
      x='Cylinders:Q',
      y=alt.Y('Origin:N'),
      color='Horsepower:Q'
  ).properties(
      width=200,
      height=200
  ).configure_mark(
    strokeOpacity=0,
    strokeWidth=0,
    filled=True
  )
```

The result is this, with the lighter color borders highlighted.

[image: Iris heatmap example with white/lighter borders highlighted.]

In the code you can also see my attempts to remove that border, using `strokeOpacity=0`, `strokeWidth=0`, and `filled=True`, but to no avail.

Any ideas how I can make the borders of the rectangles the same color as the fill color?

Comment: The reproducible example you showed does not appear to have any borders between boxes (this is seen most clearly between adjacent boxes that are the same color). What is is that you want to be different?

Comment: Hah, now I am questioning my own perception. :) I mean the extremely fine line between the borders where it appears to get a bit brighter. Maybe this is just a optical illusion (http://sciphile.org/lessons/shades-inhibition-optical-illusions-lateral-inhibition)?

But in my actual plot, do you agree that the orange does not look uniform? There are only two values, blue and orange, but the orange block doesn't look solid, like there are many darker orange borders to the rectangles? I will edit the post to add the code that created the actual plot.